# Substring excluding two strings c# return an error

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to extract a portion of the string,I use two patterns, the string I'm interested in is in the middle of these two pattern...But I get this error ... where did I fail?

> [System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a
>   location within the string. Parameter name: length]    at
>   System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)    at
>   Program.Main() :line 16

This is the code

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"<Code>";
        string _pattern = @"</Code>";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        Regex _regex = new Regex(_pattern);
        string str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\" ?><Codici QuoteParams><Code>AC-ALTRE-SPESE-T</Code></Codici QuoteParams>";

        var matches = regex.Matches(str);
        var _matches = _regex.Matches(str);
        string firstString = str.Substring(0+str.IndexOf(matches[0].ToString()),str.IndexOf(_matches[0].ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(firstString);

    }
}
```

Comment: It means that you have addressed something that doesn't exist. For example, you have a list with 5 items in it, and you ask for the 6th, or you have a 5 character string, and ask for the 6th. Personally, I'd advocate using the XmlSerializer to deserialize the XML, or XmlDocument to parse it, rather than using regex.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but I'm fairly sure [you should be using an XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/106159) to parse it!

Comment: IF you have XML document, then use proper tools for that, such as `XDocument` class or `XmlDocument`.

Comment: Thix xml is invalid

Comment: @MarcoSalerno this xml it's generated by Sap Business One

Answer (score 5):

[`String.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8) does not take start and end index, but start index and length.

The usual approach therefore is to get the start index and then calculate the length like this:

```
var start = myString.IndexOf(firstPart);
var end = myString.IndexOf(lastPart);
var length = end - start;
var substring = myString.Substring(start, length);
```

For this specific case though I would suggest you use the usual XML functionality in C# like [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8) which is more robust than using regex for this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use this `Regex` pattern to match and capture the code:

```
string code = Regex.Match(str, "(?<=<Code>).*(?=</Code>)").Value;
```

You can try it out [Here](https://regex101.com/r/pQxhPW/1)